# How to connect spark with Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am using Ubuntu and I am trying to connect spark with Cassandra I used the following steps.

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
cd spark-cassandra-connector
./sbt/sbt assembly
./spark-shell --jars ~/spark/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And After this I tried this

```
Scala> sc.stop
Scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._
Scala> org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
Scala import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
Scala> val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
Scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
Scala> val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
```

I am using spark 2.2.1  and my Cassandra is apache-cassandra-2.2.12

When I enter this command

```
Scala> val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
```

it gives me this error.

> error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'CassandraConnector.class'.
>   Could not access type Logging in package org apache spark,
>   because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
>   missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with Ylog classpath to see the problematic classpath.)
>   A full rebuild may help if 'CassandraConnector class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org apache spark.

I Find different tutorial but I am not able to solve my issue, is someone will give me suggestion. Thanks

Comment: connector version is 1.4? for spark 2.x it should be spark-cassandra-connector 2.0

Comment: Would you tell me how to install 2.x

Comment: Usually sbt or maven is used for dependency management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't download jar files and try to use them. instead just point the spark shell to the maven dependency.

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7"
```

Now spark shell will automatically download the right jar file from maven central

Comment: Would you tell me if I am using apache-cassandra-3.11.2 and spark 2.0.2 which connector should I use ?

Comment: This document contains a grid to find the compatible releases https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: I tried all but I am not able to execute would you suggest me one for my part. apache-cassandra-3.11.2 and spark 2.0.2